# Wget in windows download latest dynamic named podcast daily and rename to static name

Tags: windows, wget, podcast

i am trying to download the newest episode of democracy now using windows task scheduler and wget in windows.

it worked for a while and then somehow i lost the task schedule and now i can't rediscover the code i used.

i am trying to download the latest mp3 file from here http://www.democracynow.org/podcast.xml on a daily basis and rename to "DemocracyNow.mp3" for my automation to play out the file on my low power station on a daily basis.

any suggestions?

thanks

Ps: i'm a coding noob

Comment: If you're on windows and have got `wget`, are you working from within `cygwin`? `wget` alone is not up for this task, and the answer to the preceding question highly influences how complicated the solution is.

Comment: i got this code from another engineer that seems to work for my purposes http://pastebin.com/QMZfipbT also was forwarded this php code as well which i have not tried https://gist.github.com/refutationalist/0fd8d056de3d9c9a410a5a87a78b7779

Comment: I think it fails because your using a different locale. If you run the command  
`ECHO %Date:~10,4%-%Date:~4,2%%Date:~7,2%` on the command-line, what do you get? (This is a single command in one line - I somehow can't force the newline [as stated](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) before the `ECHO`)

Comment: oh the one liner code over at pastebin works fine for me. DN is east coast time zone and i am mountain and it works perfect. they upload new episodes @ about 930a east coast time and i set my task to download at noon my time and it has been working for a week now with no issue as of yet. the github i have not tried because the first one works so well. i just posted the github for reference purposes even though i have not tried it myself.